# CSS: true 1 pixel line?

Tags: html, css

```
.div-line {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    width:33%;
    background:#000;
}
```

Is it because of 4k-monitor rendering (don't have a non-4k monitor to test it on)  that this 1px-height div is in reality displaying a height of 3px? If I change the height to 0.5px, then it renders a true 1px height. And as you may expect, changing the height to 0.75px renders 2px on the screen.

If this is a 4k monitor rendering issue, is there code in either CSS or HTML that addresses this? I'd like to create a div with a 1px height that renders 1px on all devices and resolutions.

Comment: Aren't you viewing it as in image in photoshop? Lines generated with HTML or CSS are not images.

Comment: Take a look at `dppx` units and `dpi` units for targeting

Comment: have you tested this in the browser not photoshop?

Comment: @AlanSutherland I'm not sure what you mean. The line looked thicker than 1px on the browser so I screenshot it and verified in Photoshop that it's 3px, not 1.

Comment: Pixels (px) are relative to the viewing device. For low-dpi devices, 1px is one device pixel (dot) of the display. For printers and high resolution screens 1px implies multiple device pixels.

Comment: @Banzay so if a 4k UHD monitor (3840x2160) renders css:1px as visual:3px then an HD monitor (1920x1080) would render css:1px as visual:1.5px (rounded up to 2) and a non-HD monitor would render css:1px as visual:1px?

Comment: I think yes. I don't know pure css method to set a real 1px dimension, but using javascript you can try to get it with `screen.width` property. I mean if you divide `screen.width` by `screen.width` you should get pure 1 unit which seems to be 1 pixel.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is use media queries to target devices with higher pixel densities:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
(min-resolution: 144dpi){ 
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

### References

Retina Display Media Query: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Device pixel density tests: https://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

W3C Specification on media query resolution: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution

Comment: It's unfortunate that the browser doesn't automatically render for screen resolution. My guess is that they eventually will and not require developers to remind the browser that 1px = 1px.